# Trying too make project run correctly

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Completing the projects in the book, I am doing the first with WPF. Pretty straight forward though; when I am looking to debug the program I am running into an issue that exists in the fact that a line of code on the program is missing.

The [MessageBox.Show("Hello" + textSayHello.Text + "!");] section is in the book but not in when I design the program in WPF. Though is the section used to explain debugging. Page 16.

- This is in the book but not in the program when created in WPF. I am attempting to write it in though as I state this as the breakpoint it states that the .exe is missing when hitting F5.
- Then states that the project needs built so I build the project and the response is "The name textSayHello does not exist in current context".
- I attempted to create a .txt file with line 1 as "Hello World!" and that didn't work, maybe I am saving it wrong.
- I, though understanding the concept of programming am a novice programmer.

  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Windows;
  using System.Windows.Controls;
  using System.Windows.Data;
  using System.Windows.Documents;
  using System.Windows.Input;
  using System.Windows.Media;
  using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
  using System.Windows.Navigation;
  using System.Windows.Shapes;

  namespace WpfApp1
  {
      /// 
      /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
      /// 
      public partial class MainWindow : Window
      {
          public MainWindow()
          {
               InitializeComponent();
          }

  ```
      private void btnSayHello_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {

      }

      private void txtSayHello_TextChanged(object sender,     TextChangedEventArgs e)
      {
          MessageBox.Show("Hello" + textSayHello.Text + "!");

      }
  }
  ```

  }

Expected results are to run a debug. Then as the book states "Deploy your application".